# Kendo ASP MVC cshtml automatic code formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, kendo-ui

I usually use Ctrl+k, Ctrl+d to format my code in Visual Studio 2013, but with the Kendo UI controls in cshtml file, it does not work.  Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that the kendo.web.min.intellisense.js file is present in the folder which hosts kendo.web.min.js

Explanation can be found here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/vs-intellisense

In case , you can't find the intellisense files, search them in vsdoc file in the Kendo installation. then copy them into the project folder with kendo.web.min.js

That should solve the issue.